# Dollar Description in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Someone Please explain the use of dollar sign used at the last of 6th line:

```
function isAlphabet(elem) {
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

    if(elem.value.match(alphaExp))  
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: That function could be condensed to `return elem.value.match(/^[a-z]+$/i);`.

Comment: @Blender - Don't like the GNU brace style of "Lets put the brace somewhere in the middle of everything" style?  (Ref: Your edit.)

Comment: @Blender Actually it's `return /^[a-z]+$/i.test(elem.value)` because the return value should be a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire expression, explained

```
                |-------------- Match the start of the line
                |         ----- Match the 'end of the line
                |         |
var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
                 |------|| +-- Close the regular expression
                 |  |   ||
                 |  |   |+---- Match one or more characters from the previous pattern
                 |  |   |----- Close the group
                 |  |--------- Match characters between "a" and "z" and "A" and "Z"
                 |------------ Start a group
```

The entire thing, in English means

Match anything that starts the line with the characters `a-z` or `A-Z` and that ends the line with one of the same characters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regular expression.
It means end of the line.

What this regular expression match is a string made only alphabetic character lower and upper case.

- `^` means starts of the line
- `[a-zA-Z]` an alphabetic upper or lower case character
- `+` many time
- `$` end of the line

Comment: it is too escape `.` means any character, `\.` means the character "dot"

Answer (score 1):

In that context, it anchors the regex pattern to the end of the line. A $ most anywhere else in a pattern is just a $, but at the end it's an end-of-line anchor.

Answer (score 0):

`$` matches the end of line.

`/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` means all the characters is alphabet.

The function could also write more clean like:

```
function isAlphabet(elem) {
  return /^[a-z]+$/i.test(elem.value);
}
```